# Joomla 2.5 Display Category Page Only via Menu

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I want to display the Category page in **Joomla 2.5** only via links in the menu.

Is there a way to disable the display of a Category page by taking the id and the name of the category from the url? For e.g., if the **Animals** category's **id** is 3, http://example.com/animals/cat/3-animals will load the **Animals Category page**, resulting in dublicate content with http://example.com/animals!

Comment: Fix what? This is how Joomla! works...

Comment: Joomla is supposed to create link like http://www.example.com/our-team/about-me/77-our-team ?

Comment: Why would you add that to a URL?

Comment: Google has indexed it somehow from an old version of the site. I just need to disable the displaying of a category just by seeing it's id and name in the url.

Comment: I'm not sure you can, I would suggest trying to use the builtin redirect component to send people somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't disable the Joomla long URLs without messing up the rest of the site. What you can do rather than disabling it is to use 301 redirects on any pages that are indexed in Google so that the listings get updated and no longer appear in Google's index. Just google site:example.com to see everything they have indexed.

Comment: FYI you can also use the built in Joomla Redirect component to create the redirects if you are not familiar with HTACCESS.